# How to config 100 request every 60 sec for duration of 5 min in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I'll try to explain my issue:

I want to execute 100 req every 60 sec for the duration of 5min (300sec)
it will be like that:

60 sec - 100 rec

60 sec - 100 rec

60 sec - 100 rec

60 sec - 100 rec

60 sec - 100 rec

please, someone can tell me how to configure the Jmeter for my needs?

[this is how I try - see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBkkm.png)

Answer (score 0):

From your explanation I understand, you want to simulate 100 requests every 60 seconds irrespective of thread count. I will suggest you go with ultimate thread group packaged in [Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/) with jMeter.

Comment: I have downloaded it and install..
can you help me to configure the test I want because I can't understand it so much
look at the screenshot:
https://imgur.com/XmlKnSX

Comment: I will try to explain a bit of basics. You need to simulate 100 request every 60 seconds. If you want to do this with a single thread (read user in real time) then run a sample test first for 1 min. If a single thread is able to simulate 100 (consider a delta of 10-20 request +-) requests in a min, then go ahead and schedule the same test as you have shown in the link but put 1 thread only and schedule the test for 5 mins. That way you will have ~500 requests in 5 mins with a single thread (user).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ultimate thread group or stepping thread group for the scenario you have mentioned. You will have to download this external plugin using [plugin manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/). For using the thread groups refer to [this article](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420305-How-To-Configure-Ultimate-Stepping-Thread-Groups-Scenario-Legacy-JMeter-Test--How-To-Configure-UltimateStepping-Thread-Groups-Scenario-(Legacy-JMeter-Test)).

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have downloaded it and install..
can you help me to configure the test I want because I can't understand it so much
look at the screenshot:

Comment: You can refer to the articles shared and configure your test accordingly.